# How does this work in std::tuple; element 'has' member?

Tags: c++, stl, tuples

I recently saw this example on the net:

```
typedef std::tuple<
    CInput,
    CAnimation,
    CTransform
> ComponentTuple;

class Entity
{
    ...
    ComponentTuple m_components;

public:
    ...

    // component management
    template <typename T> bool has_component() const { return get_component<T>().has; }
    template <typename T, typename... TArgs> T& add_component(TArgs&&... mArgs)
    {
        auto& component = get_component<T>();
        component = T(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...);
        component.has = true;
        return component;
    }
    template <typename T> T& get_component() { return std::get<T>(m_components); }
    template <typename T> const T& get_component() const { return std::get<T>(m_components); }
    template <typename T> void remove_component() { get_component<T>() = T(); }
};
```

I've studied this code for hours and I cannot figure out how the template members has_component and `add_component` work - specifically with the `has` member. Where does that come from? It's not documented in the standard, anywhere I can see. Yet, somehow, the `has` member is set to true in `add_component`, and is available for examination in `has_component`.

Obviously, the goal here is to use has to determine if the tuple entry was default-constructed or not.

Comment: `has` is a member of `CInput`, `CAnimation` and `CTransform`, not of `std::tuple`.

Comment: Only if it's well hidden - those classes are also in the example and they don't have a "has" member.

Comment: This could be done much clearer btw. with `std::tuple<std::optional<CInput>, std::optional<CAnimation>, std::optional<CTransform>>`, which would avoid the extra "uninitialized" state in the classes, or even better by delaying creation of the tuple object(s) until the elements can be constructed, so that `optional` isn't required at all.

Comment: They do have `has` members, otherwise the shown code won't be usable.

Comment: @user17732522 You are correct! I just realized that the only one of those classes in my test code that I actually called the template members on does indeed have a public 'has' member. And thank you very much for the tip about optional - that is way better.

Comment: *"It's not documented in the standard, anywhere I can see."* -- Why would `CInput` be documented in the standard? (Real point: don't just say "anywhere I can see"; also state where you were looking and why. If your search is based upon a false premise, it's not really possible for others to guess what you're thinking.)

Comment: I'm sorry @JaMiT - I didn't realize I was being that unclear. I'll try to do better in the future. Of course CInput would not be documented anywhere in the standard. I was asking about a possible 'has' member hidden in the guts of std::tuple. My real problem here is that I didn't show the definitions of CInput and CAnimation - I'm sorry about that also.

Comment: @JohnCalcote *"I was asking about a possible 'has' member hidden in the guts of std::tuple."* -- This is the sort of detail that should be in the question. It takes practice, but it is beneficial to learn to explain your thinking, rather than just explaining what you did. (This is more or less the principle behind [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), which is an effective technique.)

Answer (score 1):

To provide some closure here. User @user17732522 provided the clue I needed to figure out what's going on, as well as a suggestion for a better implementation, using `std::optional`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <optional>

typedef std::tuple<
    std::optional<CInput>,
    std::optional<CAnimation>,
    std::optional<CTransform>
> ComponentTuple;

class Entity
{
    ...
    ComponentTuple m_components;

public:
    ...

    // component management
    template <typename T> bool has_component() const { return std::get<std::optional<T>>(m_components).has_value(); }
    template <typename T, typename... TArgs> T& add_component(TArgs&&... mArgs)
    {
        std::optional<T>& opt_comp = std::get<std::optional<T>>(m_components);
        opt_comp = std::make_optional(T(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...));
        return opt_comp.value();
    }
    template <typename T> T& get_component() { return std::get<std::optional<T>>(m_components).value(); }
    template <typename T> const T& get_component() const { return std::get<std::optional<T>>(m_components).value(); }
    template <typename T> void remove_component() { std::get<std::optional<T>>(m_components).reset(); }
};
```

With this implementation, there are absolutely no constraints on the types that may be managed by the tuple, with the exception that each type must be unique so that the members can find the element by type, rather than by index.

Code can then be written like this:

```
auto& anim = player->add_component<CAnimation>(...);
std::cout << "added: " << anim << std::endl;
std::cout << "player " << (player->has_component<CAnimation>() ? "has" : "does not have") << " the CAnimation component." << std::endl;
player->remove_component<CAnimation>();
std::cout << "removed" << std::endl;
std::cout << "player " << (player->has_component<CAnimation>() ? "has" : "does not have") << " the CAnimation component." << std::endl;
```

Thanks very much to those who responded.

Comment: `opt_comp = std::make_optional(T(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...));` makes two unnecessary moves. `opt_comp.emplace(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...);` will not make any.

Comment: Once again @user17732522 I’m in your debt.